# Visual Studio (2013.4) replaces Hintpath with Relative Path

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently tried working with monogame templates but I had to realize that Visual Studio keeps replacing templates hintpath with an relative path.

Project file:

```
<Reference Include="MonoGame.Framework">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows\MonoGame.Framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Template file:

```
<Reference Include="MonoGame.Framework">
   <HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows\MonoGame.Framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Why does Visual Studio replace these paths and how can I make Visual Studio stop that?

Comment: Well I expect it does that to make the project file more portable. I *strongly* prefer the latter - why do you *want* it to rely on exactly how many levels your project file is below the root directory?

Comment: I do not want Visual Studio to replace $(MSBuildProgramFiles32) with `..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)`. The project is on the same drive, which might be the problem because if Visual Studio is not working on i.e. "C:\" it does not replace the property.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, I thought you meant it was converting the first form to the second.

Comment: @AliveDevil : Did you solve this problem? Placing Visual Studio on a different drive is not an option for me.

Comment: @bwyn: I didn't investigate further and didn't solve this. May be moving the project to a different drive might help because these paths are project relative.

Comment: I ended up using a UNC path as you suggested, and it stopped Visual Studio from replacing the hint path.